# Date filtering in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

I'm trying to filter some data based around datetime and particular years. Tried two approaches and neither works. What's wrong?

This is the data.

```
surname forename    initials    age_text    honours_awards  date_of_death   date_of_death2  rank    regiment    unitshipsquadron    country servicenumberExport cemeterymemorial    gravereference  additionalinformation
0   ABBERLEY    BERTRAM B   NaN NaN 1916-11-18  NaN Private North Staffordshire Regiment    8th Bn. France  '21850' THIEPVAL MEMORIAL   Pier and Face 14 B and 14 C.    NaN
1   ABBERLEY    THOMAS FREDERICK    T F NaN NaN 1917-09-20  NaN Serjeant    North Staffordshire Regiment    8th Bn. Belgium '40791' TYNE COT MEMORIAL   Panel 124 to 125 and 162 to 162A.   NaN
2   ABBOTTS ALBERT EDWARD   A E 20.0    NaN 1917-09-26  NaN Serjeant    North Staffordshire Regiment    2nd/6th Bn. Belgium '240926'    TYNE COT MEMORIAL   Panel 124 to 125 and 162 to 162A.   SON OF MARY JANE DICKEN (FORMERLY ABBOTTS), OF...
3   ABBOTTS ERNEST  E   29.0    NaN 1916-04-20  NaN Private North Staffordshire Regiment    7th Bn. Iraq    '16414' BASRA MEMORIAL  Panel 34.   SON OF MR. AND MRS. JAMES ABBOTTS, OF 21, ABBE...
4   ABBOTTS FREDERICK   F   32.0    NaN 1915-10-13  NaN Private North Staffordshire Regiment
```

My code is:

```
path = "CasualtySearch_31_10_2012_03_04.csv"
df = pd.read_csv(path)
#Convert date_of_death field to datetime
df['date_of_death'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_death'])
#Crop out casualties outside WW1
#Approach 1

df = df[df['date_of_death'].dt.year.between(2014, 2018)]

#Approach 1
df = df[(df['date_of_death'].dt.year >= 2014) & (df['date_of_death'].dt.year <= 2018)]

df.describe()
```

But both return

```
        age_text    date_of_death
count   0.0         0
mean    NaN         NaT
min     NaN         NaT
25%     NaN         NaT
50%     NaN         NaT
75%     NaN         NaT
max     NaN         NaT
std     NaN         NaN
```

Why is this when `df['date_of_death'].dt.year` returns a series of years and df['date_of_death'].dt.year.dtype returns "int32"?

(Full data can be found here: https://www.dropbox.com/scl/fi/p4zfen4c50dtw1egtdr5t/CasualtySearch_31_10_2012_03_04.csv?rlkey=yi67e73es4c3ginwl8tqvk51g&dl=0

Comment: Unfortunately, we will not download your file. You must create a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and base your question on it. However, I have an opinion on this issue. Perhaps there is no data for that year. can provide `df['date_of_death'].dt.year.describe()`?

Comment: I have done above.

Comment: The things I mentioned in the text do not exist. Of course, I am asking you to check the values before you filter them. Run the following code and check it for yourself. `df = pd.read_csv(path);df['date_of_death'] = pd.to_datetime(df['date_of_death']);df['date_of_death'].dt.year.describe()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With your provided dataset, there are no cases who died after 1947:

```
import pandas as pd
# slicker way of processing dates
df = pd.read_csv(
    'CasualtySearch_31_10_2012_03_04.csv',
    parse_dates=['date_of_death', 'date_of_death2'],
    dayfirst=True
)

# get to know your dataset
df.date_of_death.max()
>>> Timestamp('1947-10-27 00:00:00')
```

Otherwise, the [`.between()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.between.html#pandas.Series.between) method is a very valid approach and produces multiple rows if you choose a valid date range:

```
In [25]: df[df.date_of_death.dt.year.between(1939, 1941)]

Out[25]: 
        surname              forename  ...                    gravereference                              additionalinformation
432      BAXTER  ALFRED PETER SWINSON  ...                  Plot H. Grave 2.  SON OF ALFRED SWINSON BAXTER, AND OF MARY ELLE...
438       BAYLY                   NaN  ...  Div. M. Uncons. Row A. Grave 23.  SON OF EDWIN AND ADA GERTRUDE BAYLY, OF ALDERS...
467     BECKETT                NORMAN  ...                       Grave 2878.  SON OF ALBERT EDWARD AND ETHEL MARY BECKETT, O...
564        BILL        ARTHUR WILLIAM  ...                  Row A. Grave 11.  SON OF WILLIAM AND ANNIE BILL; HUSBAND OF HILD...
599      BISHOP         WILLIAM HENRY  ...                       Column 120.  SON OF JOSEPH HENRY AND LILY BISHOP; HUSBAND O...
...         ...                   ...  ...                               ...                                                ...
6395   WILLIAMS     JAMES HENRY (JIM)  ...  Sec. 18. Plot 1. Row A. Grave 2.  SON OF ROBERT AND EMMA WILLIAMS, OF WOLVERHAMP...
6511  WOODFIELD          WILLIAM JOHN  ...           Plot 2 Row 13 Grave 25.  SON OF THOMAS AND ADA WOODFIELD; HUSBAND OF EL...
6530   WOODWARD               WILLIAM  ...           British Plot. Grave 45.                                                NaN
6564     WRIGHT        DAVID REGINALD  ...                         V. A. 20.  SON OF JOHN JOSEPH AND JANE WRIGHT, OF HANLEY,...
6574     WRIGHT                 JAMES  ...                       Column 120.                  SON OF JAMES AND MARY ANN WRIGHT.

[112 rows x 15 columns]
```

Answer (score 3):

I think your approach is correct. The issue seems to be with the data -  `df.date_of_death.dt.year.min()` and `df.date_of_death.max()` report that the years are limited to 1914-1947 (or simply `df.describe()` as per suggestion in the comments). Your filters look beyond those dates, which returns a list of `False` because nothing matches the filter. So the resulting dataframe has zero rows (as no row is `True`), and running `.describe()` on an empty dataframe gives you the `NaN` entries.

Answer (score 0):

I prefer @moo's answer - much better - but I added a few lines.

```
df[['day', 'month', 'year']] = df['date_of_death'].str.split("/", expand=True)
df[['day', 'month', 'year']] = df[['day', 'month', 'year']].astype(int)
df[(df['year'] >=1914) & (df['year'] <= 1918)]
```